# Python What is going on when I get or attempt to read an sftp file?

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

A question here that concerns how stfp operates. I am curious to understand what exactly is going on "behind the scenes" when I connect to a SFTP and download a file.

I've been using some inherited code that connects to a sftp server, and lists a directory: e.g.

```
sftp = pysftp.Connection(host='xxxxx', username='xxxx', password='xxxxx', cnopts=cnopts)
sftp.cwd('/some_dir')

server_files = sftp.listdir()
```

From there, let's say I want to read `server_files[1]` into a `pandas` dataframe:

I cannot simply attempt to read the file I wish, i.e.

```
pd.read_csv(server_files[1])
# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Instead; I must first `get` the file like the below.

```
sftp.get(server_files[1])
pd.read_csv(server_files[1])
# Success!
```

That works great. No issue there. My questions are, however:

**Where** in working memory is the `server_files[1]` object "stored"? I have executed `type(server_file[1])` both before and after the `get` operation and both results are `str`, indicating to me that the object itself has not changed. So I don't really understand where the data for that file is being held. Why do I not need to do something like `my file = sftp.get(server_file[1])`? How can it work on just the 'name' of the file?

I appreciate this less a question of how to make the code work, but rather how it is operating, but nonetheless I would appreciate some help in understanding this.

Cheers

John

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a misunderstanding.

The `pysftp.get(server_files[1])`, *downloads* the remote file `server_files[1]` *to a local file* `server_files[1]` in the current working directory, as you do not specify the `localpath` (second) optional argument.

Quoting [`pysftp.get` documentation](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.get) (emphasis mine):

> **localpath** *(str)* – the local path and filename to copy, destination. **If not specified, file is copied to local current working directory**

---

So the `pd.read_csv(server_files[1])` reads *the local copy*. It does *not* magically read the remote file.

The `server_files[1]` is indeed a simple string containing a file name. Nothing fancy.

Comment: I think this makes sense. Except by local current working directory, where is this located? As there's nothing changed in my python environment, that I can see (i.e. no new variables, no memory changed)?

Comment: "current working directory" is by default the directory you have executed your script from. Try to run `print os.getcwd()`.